# C# Add Labels to an ArrayList and take Sums with conditions

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist, label

I have a List of Arrays and want to take sums from specific fields of the Arrays.

I declare the List like that:

```
List<Object[]> fieldsFM = new List<Object[]>();
```

Then I take some fields of existing (string)Arrays and insert them into my List changing their type, like that:

```
foreach (var item in files) {
 string text = folder + item.ToString();
 string[] fields = fileToArray(text);
 object[] tempFields = {fields[0],fields[2],DateTime.Parse(fields[4].Substring(6, 2)+"-"+fields[4].Substring(4, 2)+"-"+fields[4].Substring(0, 4)),double.Parse(fields[11], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),double.Parse(fields[12], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),double.Parse(fields[13], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),double.Parse(fields[14], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),double.Parse(fields[15], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),double.Parse(fields[16], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),double.Parse(fields[17], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),double.Parse(fields[18], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),double.Parse(fields[19], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),double.Parse(fields[20], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)};
                fieldsFM.Add(tempFields);
}
```

On field[4] I have some dates, so I want to take sums of fields[11]-[20] by date, that means I have to group by date.

I want to ask how I can add labels to my list so I can take the sums.

#### Update

The data structure is an array of strings, for example:

```
[abc,abc,20170616,3.1,3.2,3.3]
```

I create a list and add in it those Arrays (but first change the type of the fields) In 3rd field of each Array I have dates and in other fields I have values. I want to take the sums of the values but group by date.

It was suggested in comments that I utilize KeyPairValue. If I use a KeyPairValue what do I have to change on the call to the *.Add* method?

Comment: your question seems to be a little confused, could you provide more information about your data structure?

Comment: Use a KeyPairValue : List<KeyValuePair<string, Object[]>> fieldsFM = new List<KeyValuePair<string,object[]>>();  or use a dictionary : Dictionary<string, Object[]> fieldsFM = new Dictionary<string, object[]>();

Comment: I have some string Arrays.
Imagine this:
[abc,abc,20170616,3.1,3.2,3.3] etc
I create a list and add in it those Arrays (but first change the type of the fields)
In 3rd field of each Array I have dates and in other fields I have values.
I want to take the sums of the values but group by date

Comment: @jdwenk:
if I use a KeyPairValue how have I to change the .Add method?